# Why does light appear to bend when seen in colorful water fountains?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

Light travels as straight rays. Why does then light appear to bend when seen in colorful water dancing fountains?
I've tried looking through the Internet for answers but I've had trouble finding them. If anyone could give me some help, I'd be really thankful! :)

Comment: Light does not travel in straight lines when it goes from one medium to another.

Comment: @user105790 you look like a person who recently joined the community so take your time around the site and find the questions which are suitable  for this website. Look at the terms and the conditions for this site. Otherwise you will be penalized with down votes all the time.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you mean this sort of thing:

[image: Fountain]

The light follows the arcs of water because it is kept inside by [total internal reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_internal_reflection). The stream of water is behaving like an [optic fibre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_fiber). Most of the light travels along the stream of water and the light you see coming from the arc is scattering due to impurities in the water or ripples at the surface of the water streams.

I note that the Wikipedia article on optic fibres shows exactly this effect for a single stream of water, with [that experiment being done in 1884](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:DanielColladon%27s_Lightfountain_or_Lightpipe,LaNature(magazine),1884.JPG)!